# Растянуть верхний блок по оставшейся высоте

Tags: html, css

Вот [задачка](http://jsbin.com/urevap/3/)

Необходимо, чтоб зелёный блок помещался внутри красного, при этом синий не должен знать о высоте зелёного.

Comment: Внутри красного рядом с синим?

Comment: Да, сразу за синим

Answer (score 1):

[Я вас правильно понял?](http://jsbin.com/urevap/5/)

Comment: Нет, слово "высоте" в заголовке употреблено не случайно. Тем более изначально блоки расположены вертикально.